# Hide div on mobile devices, using CSS

Tags: css, html, mobile, hide

I want to hide a div containing the facebook likebox widget from mobile devices. I tried this but it doesn't work.

div code:

```
<div id="facebook" class="fb-like-box mobile-hide" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage" data-width="220" data-height="250" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
```

css code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 720px) {
  #facebook { display: none; }
  .mobile-hide{ display: none; }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?
It does not work using the id or the class reference.

Comment: Do you have any other CSS rules for this element?

Comment: what is the width resolution on the device, it might be larger then 720

Comment: I even tried 960. I dont thinks that's the problem.

Comment: it works on my end.  do you have a rule for .fb-like-box lower down that defines a new display? http://jsfiddle.net/H4vzE/

Comment: No don't have anything else...

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle with your entire css, html, and any js?

Comment: I just put your code in a jsfiddle and it works fine [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4rNGV/) .  Let's troubleshoot some to see if this issue is with the media query not being called properly or if there is a problem with the id/classes. Have you tried declaring other CSS rules  under media to see if it is working as intended?  Set one of your divs background color to change when width reaches 720px.  If the divs background changes then we know it is something with the id/class being called on.  If the background does not change then we know the media query isn't being executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason (unknown to me) this worked:

```
<div  class="mobile-hide">
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage" data-width="220" data-height="250" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try these it works for me.

Example 1:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
   .mobile-hide{ display: block !important; }
}
```

Example 2:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
   .mobile-hide{ display: none !important; }
}
```

**[description link](http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/disable-the-display-none-in-mobile-devices/)**

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your page defines a viewport meta tag.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

For more information on this tag see: [Understanding The Viewport Meta Tag](http://www.paulund.co.uk/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag).

Comment: This is my viewport meta tag. <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">

Answer (score 1):

I personally think your "display" parameter is the wrong one, try using visibility instead. I tested it and it worked for me.

This one should work for you:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 0px) and (max-device-width: 720px) {div#facebook {visibility:hidden;}}
```

I think you can even forget about the use of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 .mobile-hide{ visibility: hidden; }
```

edit: sorry, meant to put visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I had this problem a while back, and for some odd reason it only worked when i put my media query rules at the end of the css. Don't know why that is, maybe a bug of some sort, but give that a try and let us know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the evil `!important` to your `display: none`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a fluid grid layout, DW already created the 3 media queries for you. To hide a DIV on phone only apply:

`#div{
display:none;
}`

The trick is,that you have to add this line to tablet

`#div{
display:block;  //or inline or anything, how you wish to display it
}`

It works for me, hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the "and (min-device-width: 0px)"

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .mobileShow {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
  
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .mobileShow {
      display: inline;
    }
  }
</style>
<!--.mobileHide{ display: none;}-->

<style type="text/css">
  .mobileHide {
    display: inline;
  }
  /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
  
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .mobileHide {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="mobileHide">
    <p>TEXT OR IMAGE NOT FOR MOBILE HERE
      <p>
  </div>
  <p> yep its working</p>
  <div class="mobileHide">
    <p>THIS SHOULD NOT SHOW On Mobile (view in mobile mode)
      <p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Source: 
https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/site-content-only-mobile-viewers-can-see-ht

This code should work, You could also do a mobile redirect, or you can use JavaScript to detect the device (android or iPhone) though I would recommend I combination of the two and take note of screen sizes.

Other links

https://coderwall.com/p/i817wa/one-line-function-to-detect-mobile-devices-with-javascript

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)