# Hiding a div on the mobile is not working

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to create a class that I can use to hide certain divs on the mobile version of the site. The CSS that I am using is

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .desktop-only {
     display: none !important; 
  }
}
```

The viewport is set to:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Yet when I view the site on a device with a resolution less than 720px the div is still visible. I can't seem to figure out why it is not working. What am I missing?
I have tried all of the suggestions listed in [Hide div on mobile devices, using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922518/hide-div-on-mobile-devices-using-css) but can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

Here is a pen to illustrate the issue....resize it to under 720px and the desktop-only div doesn't hide http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEjvbM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see it working. You probably forgot to add the CSS in CodePen.

See this updated version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azGPxG

Use the same CSS that you mentioned:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .desktop-only {
     display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I already had it added with the stylesheet i linked 
Now that the css has been added again though, it is working on the pen.

Comment: Derp! Stray brace on my stylesheet. Thanks!