# Editing bootstrap CSS to hide an image

Tags: html, css

I've got an image that is displayed when viewing the website on a computer; however, I want it to be hidden when the site is viewed on a mobile device. I've just used the 'display: none;' CSS but for some reason it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1">
      <img src="./images/testing.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-sm-7 {
    display:none;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922518/hide-div-on-mobile-devices-using-css

Comment: `.col-sm-7` is a class you probably don't want to use to hide stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class `hidden-xs` and/or `hidden-sm`.

See [the docs for more info](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

`.hidden-xs`

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1 hidden-xs">
  <img src="./images/testing.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```