# How to hide the element in the mobile version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, reactstrap

I use React and Bootstrap 4. How do I hide the element in the mobile version?

```
<Container fluid>
    <Row>
        <Col sm={12} md={3} hidden-xs-down>
    </Row>
</Container>
```

does not work.

Comment: please show your code and there are many example for this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550485/hide-div-tag-on-mobile-view-only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922518/hide-div-on-mobile-devices-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript/jQuery code, add a line as follows:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {  
    $(.your-class-name).hide();
}
```

*768 is for all devices, and if you need to add for a certain device (iPhone), use device width*.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Bootstrap 4, not 5. Use [Responsive utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/).

Comment: <Container fluid>
    <Row >                                                                                                              <Col  sm={12} md={3} hidden-xs-down>    does not work