# how to style logo on mobile and desktop in web?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner at css or bootstrap.
I want to make a page that shows like below
but it can't work now
[This is just for PC show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P7nF.png)

[This is for mobile status but logo has to be in the center of the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9x5L.png)

This is my code

```
<a href="#" class="open_menu bg-light radius_full">
<i class="fas fa-bars lh-40"></i>
</a>
<div class="col-lg-3 logo" data-aos-duration="600" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="1200">Startup 3</div>
    <a href="#" class="close_menu color-white"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
<div class="navigation_mobile bg-dark type1">

    <div class="px-40 pt-60 pb-60 inner">
        <div class="logo color-white mb-30">Startup 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="socials mt-40">
        </div>

        <div class="mt-50 f-14 light color-white op-3 copy">&copy; 2018 Designmodo. All rights reserved.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Header 1 -->

<header class="pt-195 pb-110 bg-light header_1">

<!-- Header Menu 1 -->

    <nav class="header_menu_1 pt-30 pb-30 mt-30">
        <div class="container px-xl-0">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center f-18 medium">
                <div class="col-lg-3 logo" data-aos-duration="600" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="1200">Startup 3</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Please help me
Thank you

Comment: Show your code first,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide div on mobile devices, using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922518/hide-div-on-mobile-devices-using-css)

Comment: Hi Tony, I want to show on mobile only not hide.

Comment: @liming You can just do the opposite in that link like changing `.mobile-hide{ display: none; }` to `.mobile-show{ display: block; }` and that's it. I think.

Comment: Use css media query

Comment: you should show what you did or any example you tried, so we can base on what you really need to help you

Comment: you need to use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) on your css

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
This is what i was searched.
https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488